# getting error when i do dpkg command in MAC OS

Tags: macos, command-line, mqtt-vernemq

I am trying to install verneMQ MQTT broker using dpkg. When I try the following command I am getting this error:

command : `sudo dpkg -i vernemq_<%= latest_version() %>-1_amd64.deb`

ERROR :

```
dpkg: warning: '/opt/local/bin/gnutar' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
```

If I do `echo $PATH` I am getting all these path info :

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk:/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home:/opt/local/bin/gnutar
```

Please suggest how can I solve this error

Comment: There is no `dpkg` command in macOS, in fact, there is no real package manager. Your best bet is pobably to get **homebrew** from https;//brew.sh and see if `mosquitto` does the trick for you with `brew install mosquitto`

Comment: Any idea about verneMQ .Possible to install in MAC?

Comment: There is no **homebrew** formula for anything that looks remotely like `verneMQ` - I searched using `brew search vern` and `brew search mq`. Sorry, I don't know much more than that - I have never heard of that suite.

Comment: Questions about general purpose software are off topic for stack overflow. You should try superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VerneMQ on OS X. The only thing is that you have to build it yourself.

See this https://github.com/vernemq/vernemq/wiki/Building-VerneMQ-on-OS-X and let me know in case this doesn't work.